# I cannot use an external monitor & Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, monitor

I use Ubuntu 20.04. I cannot use an external monitor. How can I make it work?

When I plug an external monitor (which is perfectly working with a Windows laptop), I cannot get it to work for Ubuntu 20.04's laptop.

Here, it is the result of typing **"lspci | grep VGA"** in the terminal:

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 630 (rev 04)

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] (rev a1)

Comment: Do you have hybrid graphics? If so then for most systems you have to select the dGPU in order to use external monitors.

Comment: @ChanganAuto: Here, it is the result of typing **"lspci | grep VGA"** in the terminal:


00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 630 (rev 04)

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] (rev a1)

Comment: So you have to (1) install the recommended Nvidia drivers and (2) open Nvidia X Server Settings, select the Nvidia card (high performance profile) and reboot.

Comment: @ChanganAuto: thank you very much! It worked.